# Flutter/Dart: How to access a single nested entry in a mapobject

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Sorry I've found simular questions but I'm not sure if I'm reading the solution right or I'm asking the right question.

I'm trying to access a specific entry in a nested mapobject e.g. How would I access the Email of Robs Kin2? **Blahblah@yahoo.com**

```
"id": 337404,
    "results": [
        {
            "Name": "Rob",
            "Details": [
                {
                    "Address": "12 Street",
                    "Email": "Blah@hotmail.com",
                    "Phone": "000000",
                    "Join Date": "2021-05-28T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "Contact_Type": "Main"
                },
                {
                    "Address": "12 Street",
                    "Email": "Blahblah@yahoo.com",
                    "Phone": "000000",
                    "Join Date": "2021-05-28T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "Contact_Type": "Kin2"
                },
                {
                    "Address": "12 Street",
                    "Email": "Blah@gmail.com",
                    "Phone": "000000",
                    "Join Date": "2021-05-28T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "Contact_Type": "Kin1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Name": "Dan",
            "Details": [
                {
                    "Address": "14 Road",
                    "Email": "foobar.com",
                    "Phone": "124245",
                    "Join Date": "2000-05-28T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "Contact_Type": "Main"
                }
            ]
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really parse your JSON into typed objects to make it easier to navigate the structure. But if you really want to operate directly on the JSON, you can do something ugly like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  final jsonObject = jsonDecode(jsonString) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  print(getEmail(jsonObject, 'Rob', 'Kin2')); // Blahblah@yahoo.com
}

typedef JsonMap = Map<String, dynamic>;
typedef JsonList = List<dynamic>;

String getEmail(JsonMap jMap, String name, String contactType) =>
    ((jMap['results'] as JsonList)
            .cast<JsonMap>()
            .where((map) => map['Name'] == name)
            .first['Details'] as JsonList)
        .cast<JsonMap>()
        .where((map) => map['Contact_Type'] == contactType)
        .first['Email'] as String;

const jsonString = '''
{
  "id": 337404,
  "results": [
    {
      "Name": "Rob",
      "Details": [
        {
          "Address": "12 Street",
          "Email": "Blah@hotmail.com",
          "Phone": "000000",
          "Join Date": "2021-05-28T00:00:00.000Z",
          "Contact_Type": "Main"
        },
        {
          "Address": "12 Street",
          "Email": "Blahblah@yahoo.com",
          "Phone": "000000",
          "Join Date": "2021-05-28T00:00:00.000Z",
          "Contact_Type": "Kin2"
        },
        {
          "Address": "12 Street",
          "Email": "Blah@gmail.com",
          "Phone": "000000",
          "Join Date": "2021-05-28T00:00:00.000Z",
          "Contact_Type": "Kin1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "Dan",
      "Details": [
        {
          "Address": "14 Road",
          "Email": "foobar.com",
          "Phone": "124245",
          "Join Date": "2000-05-28T00:00:00.000Z",
          "Contact_Type": "Main"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
''';
```

Comment: Thanks I wasn't sure what the best approach was, what's the best way to parse the object? I've attempted a few options but all seem very clunky and I thought overkill which is why thought working on the Json directly made sense.

Comment: @ukholly I think there are enough articles on the internet about that question. Personally, I prefer to write the parser manually but it really depends on the context and how of the JSON I actually need. But I cannot do it with your JSON since I am missing a lot of context so if I writes a parser, it will only end up working with the specific input you have given.... also, I don't really have the time right now to make such parser. And at last... it is a entire different question. ;)